Установка SpoofDPI на арч линукс, ошибка gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar:
Помогите пожалуйста, гуглил но ниче не понял, вобщем склонировал репозиторий https://github.com/xvzc/SpoofDPI, запустил install.sh, после чего вижу такой вывод:
[kagura@archlinux SpoofDPI]$ bash install.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--100 17132    0 17132    0     0  51347      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 51447
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--100     9  100     9    0     0     55      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    55

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Error. exiting now

Изменено:
попробовал через AUR
==> ERROR: Failure while downloading https://github.com/xvzc/SpoofDPI/archive/refs/tags/0.10.11.tar.gz
    Aborting...
 -> error downloading sources: /home/kagura/.cache/yay/spoofdpi 
    context: exit status 1 
    

:: (1/1) Parsing SRCINFO: spoofdpi
==> Making package: spoofdpi 0.10.11-1 (Thu 29 Aug 2024 03:16:03 PM MSK)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Downloading spoofdpi-0.10.11.tar.gz...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
==> ERROR: Failure while downloading https://github.com/xvzc/SpoofDPI/archive/refs/tags/0.10.11.tar.gz
    Aborting...
 -> error making: spoofdpi-exit status 1
 -> Failed to install the following packages. Manual intervention is required:
spoofdpi - exit status 1


Ну и зачем запускать какие-то кривые скрипты, если spoofdpi есть в AUR

то есть мне попробовать spoofdpi через aur качнуть? оке ща

а если очень сильно захочется нагадить в систему, то не выдумывайте свой оригинальный способ (запустил install.sh), а воспользуйтесь инструкцией.

Ну а вообще ${1} в скрипте намекает, что он ожидает, что вы передадите в него какой-нибудь аргумент, например linux-amd64 (но жаль что автор поленился добавить проверку наличия аргумента в скрипт)

Ну лол, скрипт в AUR тоже кривой) https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/spoofdpi-bin#comment-988515

Вообще там сейчас какая-то дичь происходит — автор переименовал программу и, похоже, переделал теги, чем создал путаницу в AUR, так что, может, лучше всего подождать несколько дней, пока там в AUR со всем этим разберутся

Сегодня AUR-пакеты spoofdpi и spoofdpi-bin наверно должны работать
